# use private key from java in native code with openssl

Tags: java, c, openssl

i generated a public/private keypair using java. Since i want to add the key to my code (not as file) i used

```
byte[] priv = private_key.getEncoded()
```

to get it as a byte array.
To get back the private key from the byte array i use

```
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(priv);
```

Decryption is working as expected.
But now i want to use that key inside a c application using openssl.
So i copied the byte array from java to c as a char[].
But i'm not able to convert this char[] into a private key to use it for decryption via RSA_public_decrypt(...)
I tried

```
RSA *r = d2i_RSAPrivateKey(NULL,&priv, len);
```

but this always return a NULL pointer

Can anyone please give me a hint on how to do this in c language?

Edit: Meanwhile i checked the error code from openssl and it says

> error:0D0680A8:lib(13):func(104):reason(168)

But i don't know whet to do with those error codes. A search on the net didn't help yet.

Many thanks in advance.
Greetings, -chris-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to hint from srikanth yaradla i found the right direction.
Here's how i did it:

```
const unsigned char private_key[] = {0x30,...};
size_t private_key_len = sizeof(private_key);
char* buf = (char*)malloc(private_key_len);
memcpy(buf, private_key, private_key_len);
BIO* mem=BIO_new_mem_buf(buf, private_key_len);
PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO* p8inf = d2i_PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO_bio(mem, NULL);
EVP_PKEY* pkey = EVP_PKCS82PKEY(p8inf);
RSA* r = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(pkey);
```

after doing that i now can easily decrypt data i get from the java part.

Comment: Don't forget to free the ```RSA*``` by callint ```RSA_free``` !

Answer (score 1):

Are you copying the encoded binary data or just the binary data read form the file?.
See this [How to load an RSA key from binary data to an RSA structure using the OpenSSL C Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477570/how-to-load-an-rsa-key-from-binary-data-to-an-rsa-structure-using-the-openssl-c)

Comment: Yeah, i came across that post earlier. That's why i posted my code above.

Comment: I just copied the byte[] from my java source to the c source as a unsigned char[].

Comment: Looks like this is the one d2i_PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO you should be using.You said it is working with PKCS8EncodedKeySpec.But d2i_RSAPrivateKey is for pkcs1.see this http://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-dev@openssl.org/msg02730.html